# DataTable Cell Update command updating only first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable containing about 100 rows, but display 10 rows at a time and paginates to other rows. How do i dynamically update a cell in my datatable's current page. My code seems to be updating row(selected row) of the first page, even when i am on page five.

```
var NowVariants = 3; 
var row = 4;
var t = $('#mydatatable').DataTable();
t.cell(':eq('+row+')',8).data(NowVariants).draw();
```

I want my updating to occur on the current datatable page i am on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct answer to your question:

```
t.cell($('tr:eq('+row+')', t.table().body()), 8).data(NowVariants).draw();
```

However the code above may not work with DataTables extensions that manipulate table body, like FixedHeader, etc.

Also I am not in favor of using row indexes here. It may be better to use classes or get row index of the selected row.

For example, if you could assign `selected` class to selected rows, then, the code would be:

```
t.cell($('.selected', t.table().body()), 8).data(NowVariants).draw();
```

If you can get row index of the selected row using [`row().index()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()) API method when row is selected, then the code would be:

```
t.cell(rowIndex, 8).data(NowVariants).draw();
```

Also, it may be preferable to call `draw(false)` because that will preserve current page between updates, see [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) for more information.

Comment: @H.beuhier, please care to accept or upvote the answer.